# How to pass a local variable into a global function so that the function can be read by an external Index.html file

Tags: javascript, html

I built a game using the Phaser framework. On game over, the players high score is recorded in a variable (this.inputScore). To submit their high score to the server, the player clicks a button that takes them to an Index.html page where there is a form they fill in. To avoid cheating, I want the high score variable to be passed from the game's JavaScript file (Game.js) to an input value on the form as a read only value. I have created a function (assignValue) inside the Game.js file to execute this task, but because of it's scope I cannot get the function to be read by the Index.html file. When I place the function at the top of the Game.js script (globally) the Index.html reads the function and executes it accordingly (but with a hard-coded value for testing purposes.) How can I get the Index.html file to read my assignValue() function and pass this.inputScore to the input value in Index.html?

The Game.js file:

```
  //INDEX.HTML READS THIS assignValue function AND APPLIES IT BECAUSE IT 
  //IS IN GLOBAL SCOPE. BUT I NEED THE VALUE TO BE A VARIABLE TAKEN FROM A 
  //FUNCTION INSIDE THE GAME CODE. SEE GAME CODE BELOW:

  function assignValue() {

    document.getElementById("inputScore").value = 127;

};



//GAME CODE

var CrystalRunner = CrystalRunner || {};

CrystalRunner.GameState = {

init: function() {
  //...code here
  }, 


create: function() {
 //...code here
  },  


 update: function() {  
//..code here
//check if the player needs to die
      if(this.player.top >= this.game.world.height && this.counter === 0 || this.player.left <= 0 && this.counter === 0) {
         this.gameOver();
      }
  },  


 gameOver: function(){
    this.game.time.events.stop();
    this.player.body.enable = false;
    //..code here

    this.updateHighscore();

    //..code here

   },


  updateHighscore: function(){
    this.highScore = +localStorage.getItem('highScore');


    if(this.highScore < this.myScore){
            this.highScore = this.myScore;
            this.inputScore = this.highScore;


            this.congrats = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX-193, this.game.world.centerY-20, 'congrats');
            this.congrats.inputEnabled = true;
            this.congrats.fixedToCamera = true;

            this.submitScoreButton = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX-135, this.game.world.centerY+100, 'submitScoreButton');
            this.submitScoreButton.inputEnabled = true;
            this.submitScoreButton.fixedToCamera = true;

            this.submitScoreButton.events.onInputUp.add(function() {

                    window.location.href = "index1.php";

              }, this);

      }


      localStorage.setItem('highScore', this.highScore);
  },

//THE FUNCTION BELOW IS NOT BEING READ BECAUSE OF SCOPE. HOW TO I MAKE INDEX.HTML READ IT?
  assignValue: function() {

                document.getElementById("inputScore").value = this.inputScore;

  },


};
```

The Index1.html file:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Crystal Candy Game Login</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'></script>

<script>
        $(window).on('load', function() { 
        $('#status').fadeOut();      
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
        $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
        })
</script>

</head>

<body onload="assignValue()" class="bg">


<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">


    <div class="texte">
        <header>
        <h1>SUBMIT YOUR SCORE</h1>
        <img id="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png">
        </header>

        <p>Submit your highscore and you could stand a chance to win a 
        prize!</p>
    </div>


    <div id="main">


      <form id="form-style" method="post" action="crystalhandle.php" 
        autocomplete="off">

        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label class="header-text"><span>First Name</span></label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="username" 
            placeholder="Name" title="Please enter your Firstname" 
          required="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"> 
         <label class="header-text"><span>Surname</span></label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="surname" 
         placeholder="Surname" title="Please enter your Lastname" 
         required="">
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">    
         <label class="header-text"><span>Email</span></label>
         <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" 
         placeholder="Mail@example.com" title="Please enter a Valid Email 
         Address" required="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"> 
         <label class="header-text"><span>Phone</span></label>
         <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="name" name="phone" 
         placeholder="Phone" title="Please enter your Phone No" required="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="header-text"><span>Score</span></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="inputScore" name="score" 
        value="" readonly>
        </div>
        <!-- I need the above input value to have the variable from 
        assignValue inserted into it-->

        <div class="w3ls-btn form-group">   
        <div class="wthreesubmitaits">
        <input type="submit" name="signup" id="reg" class="button" 
        id="next1" value="Send" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 
        17px; font-weight: bold;"
        </div>  
        </div> 


    </form>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>

  <!--the below js file is where assignValue() is defined:-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/states/Game.js"/></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Have you declared `assignValue` ?

Comment: Hello Akhtar, please excuse my ignorance, but how do I do that? I have called assignValue using <body onload="assignValue()" class="bg"> but that's all I have done in the Index file.

Comment: is your `Game.js` file properly included ? I mean to say when you simple do alert then is it give you that alert ?

Comment: The files you have included is not in proper form in html file. In head section only include the css files and in below closing body tag include all js files. but in proper sequence. That might be the error. and it usually happens when you have your files not in proper order.

Comment: Hi Akhtar, I have tested the link between the Game.js file and the Index file using an alert function placed globally at the top of the Game.js file. It works. It seems to be a scope issue. I am going to edit my question as I do not know how to pass the local variable into a global function. Any ideas are appreciate. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: I had edited your code for how to place js files in order. Have you seen that ? and if you pass the variables then also declare those variables globally

Comment: Thanks Akhtar for your edit. I have changed  the js file order according to your suggestion (I missed your edits at first but have seen them now). I am still battling with the issue of getting this.inputScore to be recognised outside of it's local scope. I tried declaring it as a global variable (var inputScore) above the assignValue function at the top of the script, I then defined a function below that which is called within the game script which assigns inputScore to this.inputScore but it remains undefined.

Comment: Where you jave declared `this.inputScore` ? where it came from in your game.js code ?

Comment: At the moment it is declared inside Game.js (as shown in the code). I tried to declare it right at the top (globally) but it still needs to grab the score value created in the updateHighScore function. Thus it remains undefined.